# Add a custom header to Postfix with the relayed domain

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I've got a Postfix setup that allows relays only from certain domains. I accomplish this using the `relay_domains` flag in main.cf and it queries mysql to find the list of allowed domains.

```
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_domains.cf
```

I would like to add a `header_checks` instruction to insert a custom header based on the result of the mysql check for `relay_domains` which would show which domain was relayed through Postfix. The reason for this is that if the allowed domain is .domain.com and the recipient email address is someone@subdomain.domain.com, I'd like to know which .domain.com Postfix resolved to in the lookup.

I've got the header_checks working:

```
/^From:/i PREPEND X-Relay-Domain: xxx
```

But I'm not sure how to capture the result of the domain query and use that for the header_checks PREPEND. I could also perform another mysql lookup on `header_checks` but I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Consider this case: an email intended to two or more different domains. For this case, *there is possibility* that postfix will **append two or more header lines**. Is there a problem with that?

Comment: @masegaloeh in that case it would be ok because of the way I process mail afterward but that's a very good point you raise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps, you can use `check_recipient_access` from postfix.

```
smtpd_recipient_restriction = ... 
                      ... 
                      check_recipient_access pcre:/etc/postfix/addheader
                      ...
```

File `/etc/postfix/addheader` has content like this

```
/.+@(.+)/  PREPEND X-Relay-Domain: $1
```

In [access](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) table, PREPEND action will add header in your email. In this case, this map will add domain parts of your recipient.

Comment: That may work, I'll work with our ops team to see if we can use it. Thanks!