# How to add a single header for any incoming mail with Postfix?

Tags: postfix, milter

I have Postfix running with a number of smtpd processes configured in master.cf like this:

```
# Internet facing one
1.2.3.4:25      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o ...   # internet-only overrides

# Internal facing one
10.0.0.1:10026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o ...   # internal-only overrides
```

Now, I'd like to add a single header, with static name and value, to *incoming* mail depending on which smtpd it was received on.

Example:

```
X-Gert-Postfix-Received-From: the evil internet
```

My options considered:

1. Add the [`header_checks`](http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html) option and use the `PREPEND` action in the file.

   Nearly there, but:

   - It requires to match an existing header and will then add one more on subsequent matches.
   - I don't always have a certain header present already, perhaps even a `From` is missing, for example.
   - In case you have existing `header_checks`, there's no easy way to stack two `header_check` files, I think.
2. Build a custom app that uses the [Milter protocol](http://www.postfix.org/MILTER_README.html) and hook that up to Postfix with `smtpd_milters`.

   Of course, this will work. I can inspect the mail in my own app, then inject the header there. Seems over-engineering for a simple task like adding a header. Additionally, it requires extra maintenance with the need to run another daemon app, quite some boilerplate code, etc.
3. As suggested in a comment, use `check_recipient_access` ([related Q](https://serverfault.com/q/693904/135437)).

   Same downsides as `header_checks` (see 1).

I feel like I'm missing something simple. Anyone got a better idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a custom header to Postfix with the relayed domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/693904/add-a-custom-header-to-postfix-with-the-relayed-domain)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Not really, check_recipient_access has the same downside as header_checks, I'm afraid.

Comment: Postfix parameters specifying lookup tables are just comma/space separated lists of `type:name` references, so there *is* an easy way to stack them. I was going to suggest using that in conjunction with `always_add_missing_headers=yes`, but I am uncertain whether that is a complete answer (as documentation in some places sounds like `cleanup` is adding missing headers only once *after* `header_checks` processing)

Answer (score 0):

> In case you have existing header_checks, there's no easy way to stack two header_check files, I think.

There actually is a way to have multiple independent header_checks files per daemon.

each **-o** option in you master.cf overrides a default value or any postfix configuration parameter in main.cf. To have a different header_checks per daemon (say */etc/postfix/header_checks1* and */etc/postfix/header_checks2*), you have to override each *header_checks* parameter:

```
# Internet facing one
1.2.3.4:25      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
-o header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks1

# Internal facing one
10.0.0.1:10026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
-o header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks2
```

This way you will have completely independent *header_checks* files per smtpd daemon. From there you can add rules that PREPENDs the tag you were talking about.

Comment: I've considered this, but as I stated: 1) it overrides my common header_checks. 2) all the downsides of header_checks in general. I have email arriving from untrusted sources like the worldwide internet. Not sure how this is an answer to my question given that this is in my question already basically.

Comment: To be clear; if you have existing common logic in `main.cf`'s `header_checks`, then the override in `master.cf` masks it. This is a feature, but a downside/issue in this case.

Comment: if you need a common header_checks for both daemons, just add it back in both of the 'override', you can have as many header_checks as you want, just list them. master.cf does not support spaces so you need to store the list of you header_checks files in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

**To workaround the limitations of `smtpd_*_restrictions`:**

A message - even one with "null" sender - has exactly one envelope sender. So use `check_sender_access` instead of `check_recipient_access`. The used lookup type can be `static:` because we do not care about the specifics of the return path. Add it in your list of smtpd_sender_restrictions before any checks generating `ACCEPT` results (postfix would not query additional lookups beyond).

```
# in main.cf
common_sender_restrictions =
  reject_non_fqdn_sender
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
  ..
internet_sender_restrictions =
  $common_sender_restrictions
  check_sender_access static:{PREPEND X-Gert-Postfix-Received-From: the evil internet}

# in master.cf
192.0.2.0:25        inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$internet_sender_restrictions
10.0.0.1:10026      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
 -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$common_sender_restrictions
```

Comment: This sounds very interesting and neat.  Let me try this out later!